# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Error in PHP or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to store some data in MySQL database. This is my first time using databases and i'm getting

> "Error: INSERT INTO capitulos (id_hiperlivro, titulo, ordem) VALUES ('1', 'vamola', '0') Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hiperlivro`.`capitulos`, CONSTRAINT `capitulos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_pai`) REFERENCES `capitulos` (`id`))".

Is it my PHP code wrong or my SQL code?

SQL tables:

```
    SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";

    -- Table structure for table capitulos

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capitulos (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_pai int(11) NOT NULL,
    id_hiperlivro int(11) NOT NULL,
    titulo varchar(255) COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
    ordem int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY id_hiperlivro (id_hiperlivro),
    KEY id_pai (id_pai)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1         ;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------
    -- Table structure for table hiperlivros
    --

     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hiperlivros (
     id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     titulo varchar(255) COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
     data_criacao datetime NOT NULL,
     data_edicao datetime NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin      AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ; 

     ---------------------------------------------------


    -- Table structure for table paginas
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS paginas (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_capitulo int(11) NOT NULL,
    texto text COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL,
    ordem int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY id_capitulo (id_capitulo)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


    -- Constraints for table capitulos
    --
    ALTER TABLE capitulos
    ADD CONSTRAINT capitulos_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (id_pai) REFERENCES       capitulos (id),
    ADD CONSTRAINT capitulos_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_hiperlivro) REFERENCES hiperlivros (id);

    --
    -- Constraints for table paginas
    --
    ALTER TABLE paginas
    ADD CONSTRAINT paginas_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_capitulo) REFERENCES  capitulos (id);
```

PHP CODE:

```
   <?php


    $ordem = 0;

    $colocados = array();
    $ids = array();

    foreach ($data["conteudo"] as $modulo) {

        $title = $modulo["title"];
        $tipo = $modulo["tipo"];
        $pags = $modulo["pag"];


        $colocados[$ordem] = $tipo;

        if ($colocados[$ordem] == 'box'){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulos (id_hiperlivro, titulo, ordem) 
            VALUES ('$id_hiperlivro', '$title', '$ordem')";  
        }

        else if($colocados[$ordem] == 'medbox'){
            $i=0;

            while($colocados[$i] != 'box'){
                $i++;
            }

            $id_pai = ids[$i];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulos (id_pai, id_hiperlivro, titulo, ordem)
            VALUES ('$id_pai','$id_hiperlivro','$title','$ordem')";   
        }

        else if($colocados[$ordem] == 'minibox'){
            $i=0;

            while($colocados[$i] != 'medbox'){
                $i++;
            }

            $id_pai = ids[$i];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulos (id_pai, id_hiperlivro, titulo, ordem)
            VALUES ('$id_pai','$id_hiperlivro','$title','$ordem')"; 
        }

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
             $ids[$ordem] = $conn->insert_id;
        } 

        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();

        $ordem++;
    }


    }

    ?>
```

Thank you in advance and sorry about the big post :(

Comment: This means that you have a record in one table that has a relationship to another.  Trying to remove one record in the relationship would orphan the other record.  Look into cascade operations.

Comment: Would this happen even if i'm only trying to insert data into the table?

Comment: Probably a question better suited for a database guru.. I'm one of those guys that prefers to cheat with Doctrine ORM... but it sounds like you're not honoring each of your constraints with your insert statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've tagged this with Microsoft SQL Server, but in your code you're using MySQL server. They're not the same, so I've edited your tag. Also, phpMyAdmin is just an administrative interface to a MySQL server, so that tag isn't appropriate here either since you're running the commands through your own PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT capitulos_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (id_pai) REFERENCES       capitulos (id)
```

This constraint means that for every record in capitulos with `id_pai = X` there must also exist a record in that same capitulos table with `id = X`.

Aparently you are inserting a record where `id_pai` is defined but there is no corresponding record with the same value in field `id`.